# Unit testing Grails controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller

how to preform unit test this function

```
private void secondaryRepError(def secRepCmd) {

    def repProfile = springSecurityService?.currentUser?.representativeProfile
    def productTypes = representativeManagementService.getAssignedProductTypes(repProfile)
    def facilities = representativeManagementService.getAssignedFacilities(repProfile)
    def facilityType = representativeManagementService.getFacilityType()
    def listOfRetail   = representativeManagementService.listOfFacilities(facilities?.toList(), facilityType?.retail)
    def listOfLpg      = representativeManagementService.listOfFacilities(facilities?.toList(), facilityType?.lpg)
    def listOfPipeline = representativeManagementService.listOfFacilities(facilities?.toList(), facilityType?.pipeline)
    def listOfRelated  = representativeManagementService.listOfFacilities(facilities?.toList(), facilityType?.related)
    render view:'addSecondaryRep', model: [secondaryRepInstance: secRepCmd, appType: ApplicationType.getAll(), productTypes: productTypes, facilities: facilities, retailFacility: facilityType?.retail, lpgFacility: facilityType?.lpg, pipelineFacility: facilityType?.pipeline, facFacility: facilityType?.related, listOfRetail: listOfRetail, listOfLpg: listOfLpg, listOfPipeline: listOfPipeline, listOfRelated:listOfRelated]


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to just test all the required service method invocations, using mocks -- not the results of those invocation, otherwise your test depends on those method. Those service methods should have their own tests.

Moreover, test whether the `view` is correct or not, and `model` has all the required properties.

Refer, [Grails - Unit Testing Controllers](https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#unitTesting).

[Docs](https://testing.grails.org/latest/api/grails/testing/web/controllers/ControllerUnitTest.html), will help you in getting current `view` and `model`.

Command, [grails create-unit-test](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-unit-test.html), `grails create-unit-test <your-controller-here>`, will generate the test class for you to start with.